# Eclipse and ColdFusion 9 - Report Builder?

Tags: eclipse, coldfusion, reportbuilder, cfeclipse

Does Eclipse support the ColdFusion 9 Report Builder?

Comment: Added coldfusion tag to draw more responses.

Comment: Do you mean generic Eclipse, or the CFEclipse plugin, or the Adobe CFBuilder plugin?

Comment: It is the Adobe CFBuilder plugin.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7913.html), Report Builder is a standalone Windows-only binary executable.

It doesn't mention anything about an Eclipse plugin, though if one exists it'll almost certainly be included with [CFBuilder](http://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion/cfbuilder/features/) already.

Though it's unclear if you're asking about that, or about [CFEclipse](http://www.cfeclipse.org/), or just [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) in general, so that may or not answer your question.